# XML validation error - PCData invalid char value 3

Tags: xml

I have opened an XML file in chrome browser, and I keep getting the following error:

```
error on line 1 at column 18267861: PCDATA invalid Char value 3
```

What's wrong? I have downloaded the file and checked the column in command line:

```
cat file.xml | head -c 18267855 | tail -c 10 | hexdump -C

72 c4 99 c4 87 20 77 20  6c 65
```

It shows me that the character at the given position is space (0x20). What's wrong?

Comment: You supply wrong byte count to `head` command. It's not displaying characters you want, you want character at ...61 column, but seeing only upto ...55